# Canadian visa is still valid. Do we need anything else to enter?

Tags: visas, canada, eta

I have asked this question at the travel agency but did not get a confirmation. My husband has a valid Canadian multiple-entry V1 visa in his passport (Cuba) valid until 2021. Does this mean he can travel to Canada as many times as we want without any additional documents? Is the eTA still needed?

Comment: You also need a valid passport. If the passport expired, get a new one and travel with both passports.

Comment: Unless you are an American citizen, you need *either* a visa or a eta, but not both.

Answer (score 5):

https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eta/facts.html

An eTA is only needed if you are visa-exempt (Americans excepted; they don't need them at all).  Because you have a valid visa, you will not need an eTA.